# Track google search in ajax event search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating Mozilla add on. When some one search in Google it capture the search query from q="test" it works great except :

After due to autocomplete function or ajax goole search result, the page search new query without modifying the "q parameter" !

Problem : How can i track new search by ajax is happening on page and respond according to that in j query or java-script?

Note : while AJAX search #q appended in URL with new string

Comment: lol if you only knew how malicious this sounds

Comment: you are right. I was also confused about title :P